# Implement LetsEncrypt in Spring Boot app that is being pulled by docker

Tags: java, spring-boot, docker, https, lets-encrypt

I am trying to implement `LetsEncrypt` on Spring Boot app. I am using docker to deploy, I am creating a docker image locally, pushing it to docker hub and then running it in Ubuntu using this docker command `docker run -d -p 80:80 myapp:latest` and this is just `http` so now I am trying to use `LetsEncrypt` but I don’t know how to do it. Any help or any direction towards some links would be highly appreciated. Thanks

Answer (score 0):

#### Architecture: need for a reverse proxy + a container orchestration tool

If your Spring-Boot container serves HTTP-only requests, you can link it with a [TLS termination proxy](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/TLS_termination_proxy), which will accept incoming TLS connections and forward requests to your container.

Many implementations of reverse proxys are available, which can play this role of TLS termination proxy (see [this paragraph on Wikipedia](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/TLS_termination_proxy#Servers_capable_of_acting_as_a_TLS/SSL_termination_proxy)), using e.g. Let's Encrypt as you suggest.

Most of these implementations are also available as Docker images, so you may want to rely on a container orchestration tool such as [**docker-compose**](https://docs.docker.com/compose/reference/) along with a [`docker-compose.yml`](https://docs.docker.com/compose/compose-file/) to create a private network for the two containers to communicate (or, use a more involved [orchestration solution](https://www.linux.com/news/8-open-source-CONTAINER-ORCHESTRATION-TOOLS-KNOW/) such as [**Kubernetes**](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Kubernetes)).

#### Overview of several Docker implementations

To give a few examples of Docker images that implement this, you could for instance use one of these popular reverse proxys (the first two being mentioned in [Gitea's doc](https://docs.gitea.io/en-us/https-setup/#using-reverse-proxy)):

- [**NGINX**](https://hub.docker.com/_/nginx) (also bundled in projects like [https-portal](https://github.com/SteveLTN/https-portal) to automate the certificate generation),
- [**Apache2 httpd**](https://hub.docker.com/_/httpd),
- [**Træfik**](https://hub.docker.com/_/traefik), which additionally provides a "monitoring dashboard" as a webapp (see also the [official doc](https://docs.traefik.io/https/acme/) that gives many details on automatic certificate generation)

Answer (score 0):

If you want to keep things simple (keeping 1 container only with the Spring-Boot app, without a sidecar), you can use the library [LetsEncrypt Spring-Boot helper](https://github.com/valb3r/letsencrypt-helper). It allows embedded Tomcat on Spring-Boot to obtain LetsEncrypt certificate and renew it automatically.

As the key advantage of it - it is native Java + Spring-Boot, so no sidecars are necessary, just embed the library, expose ports 80 and 443 and everything else will be done automatically.

The reason I've created it is that all those sidecars just add unnecessary configuration complexity to the application. For simple pet-projects such added complexity is not justified. Embedded Tomcat from Spring-Boot is more than enough for these kind of projects