# Connection error in apps when enabling https on example.com:8080 (Docker) with Apache

Tags: apache, docker, https, docker-compose, proxy

I will try to explain my situation but I apologize right now because I started studying the subject a little while ago and maybe I don't know how to give all the details correctly.

I recently got a script (backend and two Android apps) that works perfectly on http, but the apps have a payment gateway that works only with https. The author of the code created a doc that teaches you how to install the backend on the server in an automated way, just install Docker and run the backend with the link `wget http://authorsite/docker-compose.yaml && docker-compose up -d`.

The installation created the containers for the database and the backend files, and created a docker-compose.yaml file:

```
 version: '3'

 services:
   mysql:
     image: mysql
     command: --default-authentication-plugin=mysql_native_password
     volumes:
       - mysqlvol:/var/lib/mysql
     environment:
       MYSQL_ROOT_PASSWORD: defaultpassword

   redis:
     image: redis
     volumes:
       - redisvol:/data

   taxi:
     image: author/taxi
     restart: always
     depends_on:
       - "redis"
       - "mysql"
     volumes:
       - ./img:/app/public/img
       - ./config:/app/config
       - taxiassets:/app/public/assets
     links:
       - mysql
       - redis
     ports:
       - "8080:8080"

 volumes:
    redisvol:
    mysqlvol:
    taxiassets:
```

The backend page started working at `http://example.com:8080` and I just needed to add the same url in the apps, in the config.kt file:

```
class Config {
    companion object {
        const val Backend = "http://example.com:8080/"
    }
}
```

Everything works fine, but as I mentioned, I need https for the payment gateway to work in apps, and also to get rid of http. The author does not give this information, so I researched and found some tutorials on reverse proxy, I already had Apache installed on my server (outside of Docker) and followed the tutorials related to Apache.

My .conf file (with Let's Encrypt) looked like this:

```
<IfModule mod_ssl.c>
<VirtualHost *:443>
    ServerAdmin webmaster@localhost
    ServerName example.com
    ServerAlias www.example.com
    ErrorLog ${APACHE_LOG_DIR}/error.log
    CustomLog ${APACHE_LOG_DIR}/access.log combined
    
    ProxyPass / http://127.0.0.1:8080/
    ProxyPassReverse / http://127.0.0.1:8080/
    ProxyPreserveHost On
    ProxyPassReverseCookiePath / /

    <Proxy *>
        Order deny,allow
        Allow from all
        Allow from localhost
    </Proxy>

Include /etc/letsencrypt/options-ssl-apache.conf
SSLCertificateFile /etc/letsencrypt/live/example.com/fullchain.pem
SSLCertificateKeyFile /etc/letsencrypt/live/example.com/privkey.pem
</VirtualHost>
</IfModule>
<IfModule mod_ssl.c>
<VirtualHost *:80>
    ServerAdmin webmaster@localhost
    ServerName example.com
    ServerAlias www.example.com
    ErrorLog ${APACHE_LOG_DIR}/error.log
    CustomLog ${APACHE_LOG_DIR}/access.log combined
    
    ProxyPass / ws://127.0.0.1:8080/

</VirtualHost>
</IfModule>
```

I'm still learning and I sure must be doing something wrong, the backend still works at `http://example.com:8080` but it doesn't work at `https://example.com:8080`, but even so the backend has now started work correctly at `https://example.com`. I can access the panel with https, but when trying to open apps with `https://example.com`, as in the example:

```
class Config {
    companion object {
        const val Backend = "https://example.com/"
    }
}
```

Or

```
class Config {
    companion object {
        const val Backend = "https://example.com:8080/"
    }
}
```

the apps started to show connection error and are not working properly.

I don't know if this is the correct approach, the backend works with the changes mentioned, before it was `http://example.com:8080` and now I can access it at `https://example.com`, but this new url makes apps don't work the same way and have connection errors. If I keep the original url:

```
class Config {
    companion object {
        const val Backend = "http://example.com:8080/"
    }
}
```

Apps are back to working normally.

What am I doing wrong?

Comment: Note: your question might be migrated to [Server Fault](https://serverfault.com/help/on-topic) where it would be fully on-topic.

Comment: 3 remarks: (1) you might want to dockerize your reverse proxy, which would increase maintainability easiness, and isolation w.r.t. your host; see e.g. [that SO question](https://stackoverflow.com/q/59900814/9164010) for pointers; (2) when doing so, it is important to remove the `ports: ["8080:8080"]` line from your `docker-compose.yml` (otherwise `http://example.com:8080` will still be accessible), and you should then write `const val Backend = "http://taxi:8080/"` (3) please don't use the `links:` property as it is a [deprecated feature](https://docs.docker.com/compose/compose-file/#links).

Answer (score 1):

Replying to your question would be two-fold:

### 1. TLS termination proxy

You might want to dockerize your TLS reverse proxy, which would increase maintainability easiness (no need for some manual installation/configuration outside of Docker), and isolation w.r.t. your host machine; see e.g. [that other SO question](https://stackoverflow.com/q/59900814/9164010) for pointers.

### 2. Docker Networking

In your docker-compose.yml, when adding an extra service (dockerized TLS termination proxy), named e.g. `proxy`, in charge of handling the inbound requests on your host, you should address the following things:

- Expose the `80` and `443` ports for this service:

  ```
  services:
    proxy:
      image: …
      ports:
        - '80:80'
        - '443:443'
      …
  ```

  Note: it is typical to also include the standard HTTP port 80, in order to implement a [permanent redirection (HTTP 301)](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/HTTP_301) to HTTPS.
- Remove the `ports: ["8080:8080"]` specification from your `taxi` service (otherwise `http://example.com:8080` will still be accessible).
- Don't use the `links:` property as it is a [deprecated feature](https://docs.docker.com/compose/compose-file/#links).
- Instead, put the various containers that have to communicate each other in the same custom network:

  - Adding

    ```
      networks:
        - network-name
    ```

    in docker-compose services (`taxi`, `mysql`, `redis`), **instead of**

    ```
      links:
        - mysql
        - redis
    ```
  - Adding

    ```
    networks:
      network-name:
        driver: bridge
    ```

    at the end of your docker-compose.yml.
- Specify URLs such as `http://mysql:3306` or `http://redis:6379` within the `taxi` service.
  Ideally, these URL should be set as docker-compose environment variables of your `taxi` service.
- Similarly, specify the URL `http://taxi:8080` in your `proxy` service (similarly to the last code snippet you mentioned in your question, which would then be `const val Backend = "http://taxi:8080/"`) to access the `taxi` service from `proxy`.
  To this aim, you may also want to create yet another custom docker-compose network, common to (`proxy`, `taxi`) services.
- Note that the URLs above start with `http:`, not `https:`, given they correspond to **internal HTTP requests** between containers, and the domain name in these URL is **the docker-compose service name**.

For more details on these docker-compose networking notions, see [the official doc](https://docs.docker.com/compose/networking/#specify-custom-networks).

Finally, here is a sample component diagram that summarizes the various containers involved in the application you consider:

[image: component-diagram]

Comment: Your explanation elucidated several of my doubts, but I will still try to carry out the most advanced solutions you mentioned, for the time being I made the basic changes but the problem persists. Soon I will post more results.