# Docker: 8080 not getting a response from an nginx container

Tags: docker, ubuntu, nginx, devops

I'm trying to run a nginx docker container exposing its 8080 to my 8080 port using the following command:

`docker run --name mycontainer -p 8080:8080 nginx`

The result is this:

```
/docker-entrypoint.sh: /docker-entrypoint.d/ is not empty, will attempt to perform configuration
/docker-entrypoint.sh: Looking for shell scripts in /docker-entrypoint.d/
/docker-entrypoint.sh: Launching /docker-entrypoint.d/10-listen-on-ipv6-by-default.sh
10-listen-on-ipv6-by-default.sh: info: Getting the checksum of /etc/nginx/conf.d/default.conf
10-listen-on-ipv6-by-default.sh: info: Enabled listen on IPv6 in /etc/nginx/conf.d/default.conf
/docker-entrypoint.sh: Launching /docker-entrypoint.d/20-envsubst-on-templates.sh
/docker-entrypoint.sh: Launching /docker-entrypoint.d/30-tune-worker-processes.sh
/docker-entrypoint.sh: Configuration complete; ready for start up
2021/08/06 21:11:22 [notice] 1#1: using the "epoll" event method
2021/08/06 21:11:22 [notice] 1#1: nginx/1.21.1
2021/08/06 21:11:22 [notice] 1#1: built by gcc 8.3.0 (Debian 8.3.0-6) 
2021/08/06 21:11:22 [notice] 1#1: OS: Linux 5.11.0-25-generic
2021/08/06 21:11:22 [notice] 1#1: getrlimit(RLIMIT_NOFILE): 1048576:1048576
2021/08/06 21:11:22 [notice] 1#1: start worker processes
2021/08/06 21:11:22 [notice] 1#1: start worker process 31
2021/08/06 21:11:22 [notice] 1#1: start worker process 32
2021/08/06 21:11:22 [notice] 1#1: start worker process 33
2021/08/06 21:11:22 [notice] 1#1: start worker process 34
2021/08/06 21:11:22 [notice] 1#1: start worker process 35
2021/08/06 21:11:22 [notice] 1#1: start worker process 36
2021/08/06 21:11:22 [notice] 1#1: start worker process 37
2021/08/06 21:11:22 [notice] 1#1: start worker process 38
```

And if I check the `docker ps`:

```
CONTAINER ID   IMAGE     COMMAND                  CREATED         STATUS         PORTS                                               NAMES
7ccaaa84ftaf   nginx     "/docker-entrypoint.…"   7 minutes ago   Up 7 minutes   80/tcp, 0.0.0.0:8080->8080/tcp, :::8080->8080/tcp   proxy
```

But when send a request in my browser to `https://localhost:8080`, there are no response and keep loading indefinitely...

Checking the nginx service inside the container `docker exec -it proxy bash` :

```
root@******:/# service nginx status
[ ok ] nginx is running.
```

Any idea?

Pd. I'm rookie at docker and using ubuntu.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It seems normal to get no response, because of the following two points:

- According to the documentation (https://hub.docker.com/_/nginx), the internal port is not 8080, but 80; this means that you should try the following command instead:
  `docker run --name mycontainer -p 8080:80 nginx`
  As an aside, it may be preferable to run:
  `docker run --rm -p 8080:80 nginx`
  by considering that **the running container is ephemeral**, and can be automatically removed at stop time thanks to the `--rm` option (and thereby naming it `--name …` is unnecessary), then recreated later on without having data loss, given the persistent data will be typically stored in so-called [Docker volumes](https://docs.docker.com/storage/volumes/).
- Then, your URL starts with `https://` but usually, if a container does not involve a dedicated TLS reverse proxy configuration, it's normal that it only accepts HTTP requests (starting with `http://`); so you should rather try to browse the following URL:
  http://localhost:8080

But if you are specifically interested in providing some HTTPS support to your dockerized website, see e.g. [this StackOverflow question](https://stackoverflow.com/q/59900814/9164010) or [browse other questions involving these tags](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/nginx+https+docker?tab=Votes).

Comment: What is your OS by the way? Are you running Docker under Windows?

Comment: Because the two steps I suggested in my answer work for me (under GNU/Linux Debian).

Comment: BTW, note that before several attempts, you need to remove the initial container, by running `docker rm -f mycontainer`, or even better, run `docker run --rm -p 8080:80 nginx` each time, so that the ephemeral container is removed at stop time (will update my answer accordingly).

Comment: And if you're running Docker Toolbox for Windows or macOS, what does the [`docker-machine ip`](https://docs.docker.com/machine/reference/ip/) command returns? if you get an IP such as `192.168.99.100`, you could then try browsing `http://192.168.99.100:8080`

Comment: I'm running docker in Ubuntu Focal Fossa. The problem still persist

Comment: @xavier "doesn't work" is not a description of a problem. Please be specific (commands used, error messages, debug step taken... edit your question to add that). Meanwhile, using the exact same images and the commands advised in the above answer, it took me 2mn to get it [perfectly working as expected](https://gist.github.com/zeitounator/4ae161aacb03f988f3c086dab80ce1d3)